# TempHire Gulp Build Errors

Tags: breeze

I have cloned TempHire and opened the solution in VS2015 (update 3), but I am getting the following gulp build errors:-

Error at C:/Users/Paul/Source/Repos/temphire.angular2/TempHire/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:39:38: A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.
Error at C:/Users/Paul/Source/Repos/temphire.angular2/TempHire/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:39:46: Cannot find name 'keyof'.
Error at C:/Users/Paul/Source/Repos/temphire.angular2/TempHire/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:39:52: '=' expected.

Line 39 of index.d.ts looks like this:-
declare function spyOn(object: T, method: keyof T): jasmine.Spy;

Here's a screenshot showing the build errors:-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a compatibility issue with the version of Jasmine you are using and the version of TypeScript that Visual Studio is using. You should be able to resolve this by [upgrading TypeScript](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593).

Note that Visual Studio's installed version of TypeScript may differ from what you have specified in package.json.